# SQLite - Filtering Results With a Variable Number of Criteria

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I've been playing around with Python and SQlite for a couple of hours (learning both for the first time). I want to create a tag database for some files and filter against the tags using AND/OR operations. The easy solution:

```
taglist = ['tag1', 'tag2']

rows = c.execute("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tags WHERE tag=? OR tag=?", [taglist[0], taglist[1]])
for row in rows:
    #do stuff
```

The problem though is that this limits the criteria to however many AND/OR statements I put in the SQL query (in this case, two). How can I feed in a variable number of criteria so that the user can AND/OR as many tags as they like?

**Edit:** I've managed to hack something together, but it doesn't look very elegant. I couldn't work out how to get the "taglist" list into the SQL query. It expects a string, not a list, and even converting the list to a string didn't seem to work. I ended up concatenating it into the SQL query string.

Here's what I've come up with to AND a variable number of tags together. It does an OR subquery first to get all the id's that have a matching tag, and then does a COUNT to filter the ones that appear the same amount of times as the number of tags queried. If an id appears less than this, it doesn't have all the tags specified in the tag list.

```
taglist = ('tag1','tag2')
tagstring = str(taglist)
tagcount = len(taglist)

rows = c.execute("SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag IN " + tagstring + ") GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id)=(?)", [tagcount])
```

This seems to work, but I can't help but think there's a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python but for the SQL side of it you'll want to look into the IN Clause.

You will need to double check the python, it's what I could gather from a quick search of the syntax. (For the SQL statement builder syntax I just used what you had in your code, there might be a cleaner way to do it).

```
taglist = ['tag1', 'tag2']

s = ""
for i in range(len(taglist)):
    s+=str(taglist[i])

rows = c.execute("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tags WHERE tag IN ( ? )", [s])

for row in rows:
   #do stuff
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I managed to get something put together after playing around with the IN clause. It works, but it doesn't seem particular elegant.